# Required Comment in New Column based on criteria of other columns in power query

Tags: comments, sequence, powerquery, group

This is a table where I need to find out which invoice material batches were used sequentially or not sequentially.

I need result to be

Inv No  Date    Inv Count   Product Code    Batch   Batch Serial    Required New Column with Comments
9573334429  31/07/2023  1   57663   TAP3F20026  4   Not Traced
9573334430  31/07/2023  1   68691   UIWZ306057  1   Not Traced
9573334431  31/07/2023  0   57822   MKL3D20031  1   Not Traced
9573334431  31/07/2023  0   69422   MKL3D20028  1   Serial
9573334431  31/07/2023  1   69422   MKL3D20032  2   Serial
9573334431  31/07/2023  0   69469   MKL3F20039  1   Not Traced
9573334432  31/07/2023  1   67671   SPR3B20026  5   Not Traced
9573334433  31/07/2023  1   59175   SPR3B20064  2   Not Traced
9573334434  31/07/2023  1   70963   MKL3B23039  3   Not Traced
9573334435  31/07/2023  1   70963   MKL3B23038  2   Not Traced
9573334436  31/07/2023  1   68691   UIWZ306057  1   Not Traced
9573334437  31/07/2023  1   57663   TAP3F20026  4   Not Traced
9573334437  31/07/2023  0   69012   TAP3F20025  4   Not Traced
9573334438  31/07/2023  1   55710   TAP2F20043  3   Not Traced
9573334438  31/07/2023  0   55714   TAP3A20011  3   Not Traced
9573334439  31/07/2023  1   66966   HAP2F20114  2   Serial
9573334439  31/07/2023  0   66966   HAP2F20115  3   Serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you need to provide data and explanation more clearly.

However, this does what you want in PowerQuery: Group by Inv No and Product Code. If there is one row, "Not Traced".  If there are multiple rows where Batch Serials is consecutive, "Serial", else "Non Serial"

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Inv No", "Product Code"}, {{"data", each
      let count = Table.RowCount(_),
      difference=List.Difference({List.Min(_[Batch Serial])..List.Max(_[Batch Serial])},_[Batch Serial]),
      process=Table.AddColumn(_, "check", each try if count=1 then "Not Traced" else if List.Count(difference)=0 then "Serial" else "Non Serial" otherwise "Non Serial")
in process, type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Inv Count", "Batch", "Batch Serial", "Required New Column with Comments", "check"}, {"Date", "Inv Count", "Batch", "Batch Serial",    "Required New Column with Comments", "check"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]